# Return last insert record

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm tried below code to retrieve last inserted record. it worked but it show with curly braces. I want to get last inserted record value to print in a label

check below image link

[This is the output of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcHv6.png)

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select new
                         {
                             p.Name
                         }).First();
```

Comment: How did you add the `Product` to the context? At that point you have the last product. Why do you need to find it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re selecting a new object with a single property. So `query` in this case is an anonymous object. What it’s doing now is converting the new object to a string, hence the brackets.

If you want to display just the name field, you’ll need to print `query.Name` To the label.

Answer (score 1):

You are producing an anonymous object in your linq query, if you only need the name, then what you need to do is just project the `name` property without `new { }` expression which will be just a `string` value like:

```
string lastInsertedName = (from p in context.Products
                            orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select p.name).First();
```

and remember that `First()` will throw exception at run-time if there is no row found in the `Products` table for that we have `FirstOrDefault()` which will return `null` in case there is no row:

```
string lastInsertedName = (from p in context.Products
                            orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select p.name).FirstOrDefault();
```

In your current code example you will need to access the `name` property on your anonymous object and the anonymous object is not needed actually in the current scenario, a simple `string` is enough, but just to illustrate how to do it with the provided code bits here it is:

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select new
                         {
                             p.Name
                         }).First();

string lastInsertedName = query.name;
```

To be safe side if no row exists:

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select new
                         {
                             p.Name
                         }).FirstOrDefault();

string lastInsertedName = query?.name;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

.First() throws and exception when nothing is returned, while FirstOrDefault() returns null

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query all columns :

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select p).First();
```

It equals sql:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM [Products] 
ORDER BY ProductID DESC
```

If you want to save all columns into a C# varible then it can be used like strong type later.

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select p).First();
Console.WriteLine(query.Name);
Console.WriteLine(query.SomeCloumn);
```

If you only want Name column and strong type then you don't need new{}

```
var query = (from p in context.Products
                         orderby p.ProductID descending
                         select p.Name ).First();
```

It equals sql:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Name
FROM [Products] 
ORDER BY ProductID DESC
```

Comment: looks like OP only needs `name` then we should be pulling all the columns